# Javascript Promise Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, axios, oauth-2.0, promise

I am quite new to JavaScript and I am looking at calling APIs via OAuth2.
I have added my refresh token to a firebase real-time database and calling from there.
I am also calling the refresh via Axios - although this doesn't seem to be working either!

However my question at the moment is I have a promise that is no returning as the function never ends - and I just cannot see why this doesn't end - please can anyone after me pointers.

Thanks

```
const axios = require('axios');
const createAuthRefreshInterceptor = require('axios-auth-refresh')
const qs = require('qs');
const fb = require('firebase/database')
const app = require('firebase/app')

const clientId = '';
const secret = '';
const rToken = '';
const cs = Buffer.from(clientId + ":" + secret).toString('base64')

const firebaseConfig = {
  
};

const appl = app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const dbRef = fb.ref(fb.getDatabase(appl));

//console.log(dbRef)

auth().then((resp) => {
  return true
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

async function auth() {
  return await fb.get(fb.child(dbRef, 'auth/auth')).then(async (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var token = snapshot.val().token
      let test = await callFA(token)
      console.log('test')
      console.log(test)
    } else {
      console.log("No data available");
    }
    return true
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}



async function updateFB(token) {
  return await fb.set(fb.child(dbRef, 'auth/auth'), {
    token: token
  }).then(ret => { return Promise.resolve() }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}


async function callFA(refToken) {
  const refreshAuthLogic = (failedRequest) => {
    let authData = JSON.stringify({
      "grant_type": "refresh_token",
      "refresh_token": rToken,
    });
    let auth = {
      method: 'post',
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: 'https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/token_endpoint',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + cs
      },
      data: authData
    };


    return axios.request(auth)
      .then(async (tokenRefreshResponse) => {
        console.log('Refresh Token');
        console.log(tokenRefreshResponse.data.access_token);
        await updateFB(tokenRefreshResponse.data.access_token)
        failedRequest.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + tokenRefreshResponse.data.access_token;
        // return Promise.resolve();
        return true
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  createAuthRefreshInterceptor.default(axios, refreshAuthLogic);

  let data = JSON.stringify({
    "bill": {
      "contact": "https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/contacts/115236",
      "reference": "TEST123",
      "dated_on": "2023-04-28",
      "due_on": "2024-04-28",
      "bill_items": [
        {
          "category": "https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/categories/273",
          "description": "test upload",
          "total_value": "100"
        }
      ]
    }
  });


  let config = {
    method: 'post',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: 'https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/bills',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + refToken
    },
    data: data
  };


  // console.log(config)
  console.log('x')
  return await axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("HERE")
      //console.log(response.data);

      return response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log("Error2")
    });

}
```

`

I would have expected the JS to end however there is a promise that is not being resolved.